# Backend Developer Looking for Advice on First-Time Full-Stack Project

Tags: web-applications, architecture, frameworks, multiplayer

I'm an old-time backend developer looking to update my knowledge and move more into the full-stack space, and I'm hoping for some guidance on design and technology selection for my project. The project I'm interested in working on is a web-based roleplaying game that uses a real-time connection between the browser client and the backend server. Problem is, the last time I touched anything web-related was when Netscape Navigator was popular! I'm perfectly happy with teaching myself new technologies, but my primary issue right now is that I don't know what set of documentation I should even begin with.

What I'm looking to build is a real-time, text-based roleplaying game that runs in the browser-- essentially a modernized MUD, if you're familiar with the genre. The website will host a client for interacting with the game, and will also have an interface for modifying aspects of the game state without needing to send lengthy text commands-- updating character profiles, sending messages, etc. I expect that this would need an always-on connection to accomplish. My current thoughts are that this would either run as some form of API over websockets, or possibly a pub-sub system between the many client browsers and server, but I'll be the first to admit that I have only the vaguest understanding of either of these technologies!

Given what I've described, and the vague design I've laid out here, are there any specific frameworks or technologies you would suggest I look into (or ones I should avoid)? Does this even sound feasible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two separate challenges - the game idea and learning new technology.  You need to prioritize one: e.g. make a relatively quick decision on a stack, and learn it whilst building your game - accepting that after a while you'll want to re-write it :)

Alternatively, spend relatively longer researching various technologies, making a few "hello world" type apps, and then choosing a stack that seems right to you.

If you look at the "server" end first, using cloud-based services from one of the major players (Azure, GCP, AWS) would be an obvious choice.  These platforms have various services including event-based ones.

For the front-end, there's a massive range of technologies available - I guess think about the kind of UX you want and relative complexity - e.g. the Javascript landscape is way more advanced than when I was doing web apps in the early-mid 2000's - React (framework) would be worth a look.

The good news is that you should be able to pick-n-choose backend and frontend technology relatively independently - as long as you design a good API for them to exchange data.

Building web-based games with a rich UX is not something I have a lot of up-to-date domain knowledge on, so hopefully someone can give you a better / more focused answer.